# How to mount a folder as a virtual CD/DVD drive?

Tags: windows, mount, virtual-drive

As a follow-up on my question [VMware Workstation 8: how to fake a bootable USB stick?](https://superuser.com/q/353491/14061)

How can I mount a Windows folder as a virtual CD/DVD drive?

That way, I could mount the folder as a virtual CD/DVD drive on my host system, then use that CD/DVD drive in my guest VM to boot from.

Note: I know about [SUBST](https://superuser.com/questions/109407/how-do-you-mount-a-directory-as-a-drive-in-windows-7/109408#109408), but that mounts the folder as a regular drive, not as a CD/DVD image.

Comment: If no better solutions are found: Create an iso image and mount that either directly in VMware or eg. DaemonTools.

Comment: I don't think you can. Anyway you cannot boot from a folder since you cannot [mark it as bootable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples).

Comment: @Jens I thought about that; do you know if it is possible to make an ISO "redirect" that in fact points to files in stead of a binary image?

Comment: I don't think so, what should happen to the iso file if you delete/add files? You would have to do some hacks with shadow copies or such to have a stable image... Maybe you can mount an iso file to a folder (eg. Daemon Tools paid versions) and use it in VMware, too, but I don't guess both at the same time.

Comment: @Jens good point. I'll need to think this over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do so. A folder is a logical entity, not a physical one. You cannot boot from a folder since you cannot [mark it as bootable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples) and it has no boot sector.